# Why every ContentDocument have two ContentDocumentLinks?

Tags: soql, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I working with documents in salesforce and I notices that every file I uploaded have two ContentDocumentLinks. In this links one LinkedEntityId is id that I set when uploading the file, but the second Id is unknown for me.

[image]

Why this document have two links and how I can delete this file then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second LinkedEntityId is an owner user id.